Spanish (?) "version" of "Le papillon"?
Okay, so I remember watching the 2002 French film, Le papillon (aka The Butterfly) when I was a kid - movie about a grumpy older man who collects butterflies and connects with a little girl who goes on a trip with him in search of a particular (possibly rare) kind of butterfly. Some years later, I ended up talking to a film teacher about a film that seemed like pretty much the same plot, but with a little boy instead of a little girl - if I recall correctly, this version was Spanish, though I may be wrong. I recently tried looking the Spanish movie up in hopes of figuring out whether it was at all related to or inspired by (or, perhaps, a source of inspiration for) the French version, but no go. (When "Mariposa" didn't yield relevant results on IMDb, I even tried "Papillon" and "Butterfly," but only got the film I originally watched and a few miscellaneous titles that didn't match the story at all.) If this Spanish film exists and I'm not just going crazy, it would have probably had to come out in or before 2007. 

Does anybody know of a Spanish film matching this description (older man bonds with young boy over butterflies; from the mid '00s or before)?
If so, do you know if it had any ties to Le papillon (e.g. if one was inspired by the other)?


I'm not sure if this is it, but I remember watching La Lengua de las Mariposas in Spanish class a while ago. 
Here's the imdb page: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0188030/
It was about a young boy and school and his older (grandfather-age) teacher, but I can't remember much beyond that.
